# Фрагмент полученный из FragmentManagerопределен как null

Tags: android

Не могу разобраться в чем истинная причина, так как ошибка не систематическая, то есть приложение может отработать пару раз стабильно, а на третий бросить `NullPointerException`.

Вкратце: имеется одна активность-хост и несколько (4) фрагментов. Из фрагмента запускается `Service`, который отправляет send с уведомлением о результате:

```
 //предшествующий код в классе, который extends Service
try {
     pi.send(LeagueStandingFragment.STATUS_FINISH_WITHOUT_DATA);
} 
catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException exception) {
     exception.printStackTrace();
}
    stop();
    return;

     void stop() {
    stopSelfResult(startId);
    }
```

Но так как это уведомление перехватывает активность-хост, нужно передать результат во фрагмент. Я решил эту проблему так:

```
     @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1)
      .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);// fragment = null НЕ ИСКЛЮЧЕН!
    }
```

Как говорил выше, раз на раз не приходится и примерно 9 из 10 раз метод `onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`, который в фрагменте, вызывается и все работает на ура.

Угрохал уже кучу времени на этот баг, если есть у кого какие идеи - подскажите.

PS Может есть другой способ передачи результата в фрагмент или я что-то не учел?

Comment: так я добавляю фрагмент в предшествующем классе-фрагменте:  **@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LeagueStandingFragment lsf = new LeagueStandingFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("leagueCaption", mLeague.getCaption());
            lsf.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,  lsf) .addToBackStack("").commit();
 }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте используемую версию Support-библиотеки, т.к. метод [`FragmentManager#getFragments()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragments()) стал частью Public API только с версии 25.4.0.
Раньше он был частью internal API (хоть и имел видимость `public`, но был предназначен для использования классами из Support-библиотек) и, в том числе, мог вернуть `null` внутри листа.

Для получения нужного фрагмента можно использовать [`FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag("SomeTag")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)), для этого соответственно нужно его задать в транзакции `.replace(R.id.fragment_con‌​tainer, lsf, "SomeTag")`.

Или вообще использовать другой механизм оповещений, например, [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Протестирую с тагами. По поводу LocalBroadcastManager (цитата из Б. Харди и Б.Филлипс): "sendBroadcastSync(Intent intent) не поддерживает отправку и получение широковещательных интентов в разных потоках.". Тоесть если я правильно понял, отправка send из класса-сервиса не будет доставлена в активность-хост главного потока. Или Вы имели ввиду отправку оповещения из активности-хоста в фрагмент?

Comment: з.ы. Вчера нашел закономерность появления данного бага: данный фрагмент превращается в null если его "перескочить" из следующего обратной навигацией  при положении экрана landscape?! Все фрагменты у меня используют setRetainInstance(true), весьма странное поведение...

Comment: При `sendBroadcastSync` событие `onReceive` у получателей выполняется на том же треде, где был вызван данный метод (собственно это следует из названия и документации).
Нужен именно синхронный вызов? Чтобы просто оповестить фрагмент из сервиса вполне подойдет вызов `sendBroadcast` в receiver, который зарегистрирован сразу во фрагменте (без проксирования через активити).

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо за помощь. FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag - ЭТО РЕШИЛО ПРОБЛУМУ!